# How to draw line passing three points in xy-plane

Tags: tikz-pgf

My question is , In my MWE i would like to draw a line passing through three points (-100, 700) , (100, 600) and (300, 500). further how can i label that line i mean how can i write the mathematical equation of line near by it.

**Here what i have done so far.**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-3,0) -- (6,0)node[right]{$x$};
  \draw[thick,latex-latex] (0,-3) -- (0,6)node[above]{$y$};
  \node at (-0.3,-0.3) {};
  \foreach \x/\l in {-2/-300,-1/-100,1/100,2/300,3/500,4/700,5/900}{
    \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,label=below:$\l$] at (\x,0) {};
    \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,label=left:$\l$] at (0,\x) {};
  }
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can highlight code-blocks using the `{}` button on the gui -- or by indenting them four spaces. Btw, you have a very unusual choice of scale: `1 -> 100` and `2 -> 300` ... !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pure [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) solution that is similar to the original posting (using `axis` as Marco has done is arguably more correct!).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[point/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,blue}]
  \draw[latex-latex] (-3,0) -- (5,0)node[right]{$x$};
  \draw[latex-latex] (0,-3) -- (0,5)node[above]{$y$};
  \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \lab using int(200*\x)] in {-2,-1,1,2,3,4}{
    % scaling 1:200. Have tikz compute the labels via evaluate
    \draw[thin](\x,-0.1)--node[below=1mm]{$\lab$}++(0,0.2); % draw ticks on
    \draw[thin](-0.1,\x)--node[left=1mm]{$\lab$}++(0.2,0);  % the axes
  }
  \draw[<->,thick,blue](-2,4.25)--node[above=3mm,right]{$y=650-\frac12x$}(4,1.25); % our line
  \node[point] at (-0.5,3.5){}; % the styling for point above controls 
  \node[point] at (0.5,3)   {}; % hat these look like
  \node[point] at (1.5,2.5) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is what you really wanted. I do not understand the double arrow to the axis.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
                axis y line=middle,
                axis x line=middle,
                xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
                enlargelimits=0.2,
                xmin=-300,xmax=900,
                ymin=-300,ymax=900,
                       ]
\addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(-100,700) (100,600) (300,500)};
\node[black] at (400,649.5) {\footnotesize{$y=-\frac{1}{2}x+650$}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution using the `datavisualization` library from *tikz*. The function is drawn twice by two different approaches:

- Plot points (*set=points*, cyan)
- Function definition (*set=func*, red)

The axes are a adapted to the question asked. Without the `include value` the axes would be much shorter. Also you need to scale the axes by `length=<>` to limit the size of the picture.

If you want to add markers at the position of your datapoints, you can use `points={style={mark=*, mark options={<...>}, cyan}}` as style definition.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[
        school book axes,
        all axes={length=4cm, include value=1000, include value=-200},
        x axis={ticks={step=200}, label=$x$},
        y axis={ticks={step=500, major also at={650}}, grid={major at={650}}, label=$y$},
        visualize as line/.list={points, func},
        points={style={cyan}},
        func={
            style={red, ultra thick},
            pin in data={text={$y=-\frac{1}{2}x+650$}, when=x is 100}   
        },
    ]
    data [set=points] {
        x, y
        -100, 700
        100, 600
        300, 500
    }
    data [set=func, format=function] {
        var x : interval [-100:300] samples 100;
        func y = -.5 * \value x + 650;  
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]